# C# Game Engine simulating game camera/view

Tags: c#, view, gdi+

I'm new on here, but have referred to this site for years when ever I had an issue. You guys are very helpful. Unfortunately, what I am looking to achieve, I have not been able to find anywhere.

I am building a Game Engine in C# GDI+, and it is going surprisingly well(considering how powerless GDI+ is for games).

I am attempting to simulate views. So if the view is at a position, the GameObject position is updated(In an Engine.Loop() loop) based on the `ViewX` and `ViewY` positions. For example:

```
obj.X -= ViewY;
obj.Y -= ViewY;
```

In practice, this works. The view moves, and the GameObject's all sit in the right positions. The issue though, is when I return the values of the objects, they are only returning that position, and if the ViewX position is for example, set to 1, the objects all move, looking like the view is moving... Except the view isn't.

Heres the code for the game loop(pretty self explanatory):

```
                //Game loop
            if (objects.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (GameObject obj in instances)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (obj.Active) //Only perform this action if the object is currently active
                        {
                            if (RectangleInsideView(obj.X, obj.Y, obj.Width, obj.Height))
                            {
                                obj.Draw();
                            }
                            obj.Step();

                            //It's because it is constantly updating the object position based on the views position rather than accepting where the view is and
                            //Just relating it's position to it. 
                            //Eg. if ViewX = 2, obj.X is = obj.X -2...
                            //We some how need to have a false X and Y variable to set and return...
                            obj.X = obj.X - ViewX;
                            obj.Y = obj.Y - ViewY;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { }
                }
            }
```

I know why it's happening, but I don't understand how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't relly understand the question, but that sounds wrong:

> So if the view is at a position,  the GameObject position is
>   updated(In an Engine.Loop() loop) based on the ViewX and ViewY
>   positions.

```
obj.X = obj.X - ViewX;
obj.Y = obj.Y - ViewY;
```

There are Objects that have a position. The View just paint the objects. If you work with GDI+ for a game, there is much to do!

### Here is somthing??

```
foreach (GameObject obj in instances)
{
    if (obj.Active) //Only perform this action if the object is currently active
    {
        // obj.X -= ViewY and obj.Y -= ViewY;;
        GameObject objCopy = view.convertViewIn();

        Point[] points = view.convertToScreenCoords(objCopy.getPoints());
        Point a = ps[0];
        Point b = ps[1];
        graphics.DrawLine(usePen, a.X, a.Y, b.X, b.Y);
    }
}

public override Point[] convertToScreenCoords(IList<Vector3D> list)
{
    Point[] points = new Point[list.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        points[i] = convertToScreenCoords(list[i]);
    }
    return points;
}

public override Point convertToScreenCoords(TheoCAD.Maths.Vector3D coords)
{
    return coords.GetTransformedCoord(this.matrixRotateScaleToScreen).toPoint();
}

public Vector3D GetTransformedCoord(Matrix3D matrix)
{
    double[] result = new double[4];
    double[] temp = new double[4];
    temp[0] = this.X;
    temp[1] = this.Y;
    temp[2] = this.Z;
    temp[3] = 1d;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        result[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
        {
            result[i] += matrix[i, j] * temp[j];
        }
    }

    if (Math.Abs(result[3]) >= 1e-8)
    {
        result[0] /= result[3];
        result[1] /= result[3];
        result[2] /= result[3];
    }
    return new Vector3D(result[0], result[1], result[2]);
}
```

I would recomend "Killer Game Programming in Java". There is how to do something like that.
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007300.do

Comment: Oh damn. It was so obvious. I knew asking on here would be a good idea.

Thank you. 

For anyone wanting to know the solution, I have my own methods for drawing to the screen/GameObject. Instead of using the object position, I just set the x/y coordinates in the drawing methods relative to the view, and it works! 

Thanks Tom.

Comment: Can I post a GIF here to show you the results?https://s30.postimg.org/5zx174p1t/gif.gif